# Fluttertoast problem: Member not found: 'Overlay.maybeOf'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
    /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-8.1.3/lib/fluttertoast.dart:165:28: Error: Member not found: 'Overlay.maybeOf'.
    var _overlay = Overlay.maybeOf(context!);
                           ^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-8.1.3/lib/fluttertoast.dart:154:18: Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
framework.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.
    if (context?.mounted != true) {
                 ^^^^^^^
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
```

After adding fluttertoast in my project it shows this problem while I run project on my device.
Now, what does it mean?

I was trying to show toast when an error or success occurred. But without snackbar fluttertoast is the only option to do.
But after adding dependency this problem showed.

Comment: hey @Sourav, If you have any Solution Please update here, as I am also facing the same issue since this morning, it was working fine till Yesterday

Comment: I resolve mine by using fluttertoast: 8.0.9 instead !!!

Comment: Hey, @KartikAgarwal I replaced flutter toast with getx snackbar. Because in getx it doesn't required any context for showing snackbar. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 11):

**Update: Found the actual issue:**

Flutter toast `v8.1.3` cannot work with a Flutter version older than 3.7.0 because of a [breaking change](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/supplemental-maybeOf-migration) in `Flutter v3.7.0`. You have to either use `fluttertoast v8.1.2` or you have to upgrade your flutter version to `v3.7.0`+.

**Old Answer**

I faced a similar issue after running the `flutter pub upgrade` but even after rolling back the changes in the `pubspec.yaml` file, I got the same error. But this issue was fixed after rolling back the changes in the `pubspec.lock` file. Make sure to do `flutter clean` after reverting changes in `pubspec.lock` file.

Answer (score 5):

I also came across the same problem,
Due to some limitations I was not able to change the flutter version, and Changing the version of fluttertoast has not led to any success. so what I do is try some other  alternatives

```
toast: ^0.3.0
https://pub.dev/packages/toast
```

I removed fluttertoast completely from the project and install a new dependency by running the command in the terminal

```
flutter pub add toast
```

usage:

```
Toast.show("Toast plugin app", duration: Toast.lengthShort, gravity:  Toast.bottom);
```

Comment: Docs on pub.dev say to call `ToastContext.init(context);` Since that didn't compile, I used `ToastContext().init(context);`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
 if (!mounted) return;
 snackBar(yourText, context);//or use your fluttertoast
```

if you had any problem or question i'm here to answer.

happy coding.

Comment: Hello @Amirali
Member not found: 'Overlay.maybeOf' is from auto generated file (read only),

Comment: ooow, i thought you wrote that by yourself, I understand what you mean, try not to use the latest version. I myself use 8.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this error is caused by a version incompatibility between the fluttertoast package and your version of Flutter. The Overlay.maybeOf method was removed in Flutter 2.0 and replaced with Overlay.of, which is likely what the fluttertoast package is using.

In order to fix this error, you can try upgrading to the latest version of fluttertoast, or if that doesn't work, downgrade your version of Flutter to a version compatible with the version of fluttertoast you are using.